# How to edit UTF-8 files with vim

Tags: ssh, locale, encoding, vi, utf-8

How can I edit UTF-8 files with vim?

There is a problem with german special characters like 'Ä', 'ü'. There are some in the comments. vim shows `Ã~D` instead of 'Ä' and  `Ã¼` instead of 'ü' then. (I hope there is no encoding problem on your browser :)

I have no "~/.vimrc" file.

In the "~/.viminfo" is

```txt
...
# Value of 'encoding' when this file was written
*encoding=latin1
...
```

If I enter `locale`, it gives `LANG=C.UTF-8`. It was `LANG=C` but I changed with `export LANG=C.UTF-8`. But nothing changed.

I'm using **MobaXterm 11.0** to get access from a Win10 computer. Maybe there is the problem?

(Linux v. "Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS")

---

**Update:**

- MobaXterm was already (and still is) set to UTF-8
- I have changed with [CTRL] + right mouse key (then there is a menu) the shell to UTF-8.
- In addition I set `export LC_TYPE=de_DE.UTF-8` (**"de_DE"**!)

Now it works a bit better :-|

- more and cat works
- less and **vi not**

With **`set enc:utf8`** in **vi**, it works there. (So vi is a little part of the solution)

And about `less` I should maybe read the manpages...?

Comment: What's the problem you have with UTF-8 files?

Comment: There are german comment in the files. So there shoud be an 'Ä' but vi shows something like 'A~D' (whith an ~ on the head of the 'A').

Comment: Does it show correctly if you `cat` the file? What is your `LC_CTYPE`?

Comment: No, its the same. If I pipe the result to `less` there is "<C3><84>" instead of "Ä" (bash is not in UTF-8)

Comment: So it's not Vim but pretty everything that's broken. What value do you have for  `LC_CTYPE`?

Comment: This is still "C" like everything else but `LANG` and `LANGUAGE`. `LC_CTYPE="C"`

Comment: Try with a UTF-8 locale for `LC_CTYPE` (`C.UTF-8`  should work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the encoding of the file is messed up you can let Vim now by entering these commands:

```
: set enc=utf8
: set fenc=utf8
```

The first command controls how the content is displayed, the second how it is written to disk.

However, the problem with wrong encoding could also be in a SSH-client like putty for instance, if you try to edit over SSH. If so have a look at Putty setting to get right encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .vimrc:

```
function! Latin()     
  silent! exe "e! ++enc=latin1"    
endfunction

function! Utf8()
  silent! exe "e! ++enc=utf-8" 
endfunction
```

Call this way typing Esc and ':'

```
:call Utf8()
```

or

```
:call Latin()
```